# Livewire modal auto close when delete/backspace last character

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

Modal auto close when I'm delete last character or delete all characters in input text username.
When I disabled **x-data="{ showModal: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')).defer }"** on modal.blade.php it working and not close when delete last character but modal not close when I'm click close modal.

**user.blade.php**

```
<x-partials.modal wire:model="showModal" class="max-w-2xl" head-name="Add User">
 <input type="text" wire:model="username" />
</x-partials.modal>
```

**modal.blade.php**

```
<div
    class="fixed inset-0 z-[100] flex flex-col items-center justify-center overflow-hidden px-4 py-6 sm:px-5"
    role="dialog"
    x-data="{ showModal: @entangle($attributes->wire('model')).defer }"
    x-show="showModal"
    x-on:keydown.escape.window="showModal = false"
>
 {{ $slot }}
</div>
```